# Fast list interpolation over common x,y for multiple variables

Tags: interpolation, list-manipulation

I have a (long, >50K elements) unstructured list with a header similar to;

```
AList[[1]] = {x,y,z,var1,var2,var3,var4,...,varN}
```

I want to interpolate z, var1, var2, ... , varN over x,y.  IE. var1 dependent on x and y but not z,  Is there an efficient way to do this?

Currently I've got a table with a separate interpolate for each variable which takes a `long' time to compute.

```
Table[
    InterZ = Interpolation[{#[[1]],#[[2]],#[[3]]} &/@ AList, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
    InterVar1 = Interpolation[{#[[1]],#[[2]],#[4]]} &/@ AList, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
    InterVar2 = Interpolation[{#[[1]],#[[2]],#[5]]} &/@ AList, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
    ....
    InterVarN = Interpolation[{#[[1]],#[[2]],#[N+3]]} &/@ AList, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
];
```

Is there a better solution?

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably write this

```
Interpolation[AList[[All, {1, 2, #}]], InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ Range[3, maxN + 3]
```

It's probably a little bit faster than what you have. BTW it looks in your example as if the header is not actually a part of `AList`, if it is you should remove it using `Rest`, i.e. `Rest[Alist][[All..`.