# Combining two list function (Is it the best way?)

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, interpolation

Suppose I have two list,

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 6.5, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {12, 10, 10, 10, 12, 10, 11, 11, 10, 11}}
list2 = {{1.2, 3, 3.5, 5.5, 6.2, 6.5, 7.8, 9, 10}, {12, 10, 10, 10, 12, 10, 11, 11, 10}}
```

If I plot it,

```
a1 = ListPlot[{Transpose[list], Transpose[list2]}, PlotRange -> {0, 20}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

I do want to add this plot, then I did

```
f = Interpolation[Transpose[list]]
g = Interpolation[Transpose[list2]]
```

and I got

```
Plot[f[x] + g[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

But When I try with little big data, it is very slow process. 
Is it the best way to combine the two list plot? or do we have some buildin code?

Comment: Honestly this seems a pretty reasonable way to do what you want. The only thing you might consider is to use `ListLinePlot[Transpose[list]]` to generate the plots of the original lists, rather than plotting the interpolating functions.

Comment: refer to [4994](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4994/how-to-reduce-the-interpolatingfunction-building-overhead), [61638](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61638/fast-list-interpolation-over-common-x-y-for-multiple-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is much faster then `Plot` (but the use depends on your quality needs)

```
Graphics[Line@Transpose[{#, f[#] + g[#]}]] & @ Range[1.2, 10, 0.01];
```

[image]

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[{Transpose[list], Transpose[list2]}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 30}],
 Graphics[Line@Transpose[{#, f[#] + g[#]}]] &@Range[1.2, 10, 0.1]
 ]
```

---

**Some note on time**

```
Plot[f[x] + g[x], {x, 1.2, 10}]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.018, Null} *)

Graphics[Line@Transpose[{#, f[#] + g[#]}]] & @ Range[1.2, 10, 0.01]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0037, Null}*)
```

Comment: @SaesunKim, thank you for accepting.